# Delphi failover needs to reconnect to the database

Tags: postgresql, delphi, failover, datasnap, devart

I was trying to implement the failover available here

http://www.andreanolanusse.com/en/implementing-failover-and-load-balancing-in-datasnap-2010/

but if I add a database connection and kill the first server, when I use some of the remote functions or '.open' a TClientDataSet 2 times, it throws an exception and I need to reconnect to the database again.

Expected:  '{' found:  '-+0-9.' at position:  84
{"result":[{"rows":[0]},{"data":[44,#192#16#0(nabas - (Server 213) pacote36-trafegusgr]}]}#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0

(the error message contains about 23000 of those '#0')

It works if I reconnect but when you have to implement in a system that have hundreds of '.open' and remote method calls it isn't the best option.

And since the error is only thrown the second time I click the button and call the method, it looks like it doesn't need to reconnect, it must be something I'm doing wrong.

Here's the project:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6YhWGZN7O24Zl9pYkx6d3hrdDA/view?usp=sharing

it uses the postgresql connection from devart (DevartPostgreSQL)